# Django User permissions/views?

Tags: python, django, view

I'm using Django class based views.

views.py

```
class ReportListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Report

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Report.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset


class ReportDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Report


class ReportUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Report


class ReportCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report


class ReportDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Report
```

As you can see, these are the most generic views, but they should all represent data for only the current user.

Currently any user can see/view other users data.

One way I saw was that people would define their get_queryset method, like above. This approach only filters rendered data, but the user can still access forbidden data through url (provided he knows/guesses the id).

How can I restrict access to other users resources?

Comment: You have to implement the access control yourself. How can django know what users are permitted to access? There are a few extensions that provide this kind of functionality beyond the builtin auth groups and permissions. Django guardian comes to mind.

Comment: Before accessing any view, make sure the current user is the owner of the instance viewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.  I created a Mixin where the queryset is evaluated against the user.

```
class BaseMixin(object):    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return DnevnaBiljeska.objects.filter(igrac=self.request.user.igrac)

class ReportListView(LoginRequiredMixin, BaseMixin, ListView):
    model = Report
```

This way i can call super on further queryset filtering for each view individually.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing any view, make sure the current user is the owner of the instance viewed

```
class ReportDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Report

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        obj = super(Report, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
        if obj.user != self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using this vs get_queryset? get_queryset works on detail/update/delete views exactly the same as get_object, and django raises 404 automatically.

Comment: I think `get_query_set()` to deal with a list of objects, determines the list of objects that you want to display, whereas get_object when you just want to get an object from the db. In your case, Update, Delete, View, should use `get_object()`